Share angular 17 built file (main.js) to other site
I have published angular app to website a.com.
The index.html file of website a.com contains the important line below
<script src="main.js" type="module"></script>

I have a website b.com.
The index.html file of website b.com contains lines...
<script src="http://a.com/main.js" type="module" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

The problem is the website b.com get error..
Access to script at 'http://a.com/main.js' from origin 'http://b.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
How to solve this problem?
How to share main.js to website b.com without error.
Sorry for bad English.
Thanks.
How to solve this problem.

Does this answer your question? How does the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header work?
